# Objective-C @implementation variables

Tags: objective-c, interface, implementation

What is the difference that two code ? And which role has the variables ?

```
@interface ClassX : NSObject{

int variable;

}
@end


int variable;
@interface ClassY : NSObject{

}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, you're creating an instance variable. In the second example, you're creating a global variable. Instance variables are part of the instance of a class, whereas global variables are not tied to a class.

Comment: When i write a basically program for inheritance mother class of program like first code part always return variable to 0. thanks

Comment: @wade-watt: Instance variables are, by default, set to 0. You have to initialize them in the class's constructor.